# Attributes of referenced user are all nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a post that can accept comments and those comments belong to the user and the post. I can successfully create a comment and it will be associated with the post and the user (checked that by going into console, the user_id and post_id is there), but when I try to call a user's attribute (such as user.username) it does not work. If I call a post's attribute (such as post.body) it works. When making the comments model I have referenced the user and post in my migration. In my user.rb I have also tried using `has_many :comments, through: :posts` but that did not work.

**user.rb**

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  has_many :posts, dependent: :destroy
  has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy
end
```

**comment.rb**

```
class Comment < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :post
  belongs_to :user
end
```

**post.rb**

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
    has_many :comments, dependent: :destroy            
end
```

**comments_controller.rb**

```
class CommentsController < ApplicationController
    before_action :findpost

    def create
        @comment = @post.comments.build(comment_params)
        @comment.user_id = current_user.id
        if @comment.save
            redirect_to post_path(@post)
        else
            flash[:alert] = "Check the comment form"
        end
    end

    def comment_params
        params.require(:comment).permit(:body)
    end

    private

    def findpost
        @post = Post.find(params[:post_id]) 
    end
end
```

**The migration**

```
class CreateComments < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.0]
  def change
    create_table :comments do |t|
      t.string :body
      t.references :user, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :post, null: false, foreign_key: true      
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

**The specific error I get**

```
undefined method `username' for nil:NilClass
```

**Where `comment.user.username` is being called**

```
<%= render partial: 'comments/form' %>
<% if @post.comments.count > 0 %>
  <%= @post.comments.each do |comment| %>
    <div>
      <%= link_to author_path(id: comment.user.username) do %>
      <%= comment.user.username %>
      <p><%= comment.body %></p>
    </div>
  <% end %> 
<% end %>
```

This error is at `comment.user.username`. The main problem is that whatever attribute that I call for `comment.user` it always returns nil (even something like id).

Comment: Where are you getting the error?

Comment: So what you are calling `.username` on is `nil`.  Are you trying to call it through the association like `comment.user.username` ?

Comment: I am getting the error at ```comment.user.username```. The user is valid but any attributes of the user are nil.

Comment: @guest0197 Can you show us the code where you call `comment.user.username`?

Comment: Note that `@comment.user_id = current_user.id` is better written as `@comment.user = current_user`. This avoids `@comment.user` having to reload the user from the database.

Comment: I have updated the post to include where I called ```comment.user.username```. I have also changed my comments controller to ```@comment.user = current_user```

Comment: Is it possible that your comments table contains a "bad" row with no `user_id`? Try `Comment.where(user_id: nil)` from the console.

Comment: It responded with "null". I have also tried to delete all my comment by doing ```Comment.delete_all``` (which was 0).